# Automapper error- Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: model-view-controller, automapper

I am currently implementing a WebApi. I basically need to populate all the products from the database and using the EntityFramework database First Approach. I need to automap my Buisness objects and Data objects in the provider class. However doing so , I get the following error

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nProducts -> Products\r\nProductManagement.DataOjects.Entities.Products -> 
ProductManagement.Models.Products\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nIEnumerable`1[0]\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nProductManagement.DataOjects.Entities.Products"}
```

Here is my dataobject

```
namespace ProductManagement.DataOjects.Entities
{
    public class Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
      }
 }
```

Here is my Buisness Object

```
namespace ProductManagement.Models
{
    public class Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Here is my repository class that uses linq to fetch the data

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<ProductManagement.DataOjects.Entities.Products> GetProductData()
        {
            using (var dbProductEntities = new ProductManagement.DataOjects.Ef.RansangEntities())
            {
                return (from a in dbProductEntities.vw_Products
                        select new ProductManagement.DataOjects.Entities.Products
                        {
                            Id = a.Id,
                            Name = a.Name,
                            Code = a.Code,
                            ReleaseDate = (DateTime)a.ReleaseDate

                        }).ToList().AsEnumerable();
            }
        }


    }
```

Here is my Provider class where I have implemented the Automapper

```
 public class ProductProvider : IProductProvider
    {
        private readonly  IProductRepository _productRepository;


        public ProductProvider(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            _productRepository = productRepository ;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Products> GetProductData()
        {
            var productData = _productRepository.GetProductData();
            var productViewData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductManagement.DataOjects.Entities.Products>, IEnumerable<ProductManagement.Models.Products>>(productData);
            return productViewData;

        }


    }
```

Can somebody tell what the problem would be ?

Comment: Have you defined your mappings anywhere -- via `CreateMap`?

Comment: No. I havent. Do you have too ? Could you let me know where and how to do it ?

Comment: See: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Write it like to your model class:

public class Products : IMapFrom < YourBusnessEntityToMap >

Now it will work fine. :)